# How to count missed Parts from Table Trade and that Exist On Table Parts?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I work on sql server 2012 I face issue I can't get missed parts from trade code table and exist on table parts .

first I upload data of plid and codetypeid on table search data .

second I get related parts from table parts based on plid .

third i get missed parts from table trade code .

meaning I need to get parts exist on table parts and related to table search data and not exist on table trade code

Data Sample :

```
create table #searchdata
(
plid int,
codetypeid int
)
insert into #searchdata
(plid,codetypeid)
values
(84459,877490)

create table #parts
(
partid int,
plid int
)
insert into #parts(partid,plid)
values
(758901,84459),
(808091,84459),
(509030,84459),
(7090321,84459),
(32453,84459),
(45563,84459)

create table #tradecode
(
partid int,
codetypeid int
)
insert into #tradecode(partid,codetypeid)
values
(758901,877490),
(808091,877490)

select p.plid,s.codetypeid,count(p.partid) as countmissingParts
from #parts p
inner join #searchdata s on s.plid=p.plid
left join #tradecode t on t.codetypeid=s.codetypeid
where t.partid is null
group by p.plid,s.codetypeid
drop table #searchdata
drop table #parts
drop table #tradecode
```

what I try :

```
select p.plid,s.codetypeid,count(p.partid) as countmissingParts
from #parts p
inner join #searchdata s on s.plid=p.plid
left join #tradecode t on t.partid=s.plid 
where t.partid is null
group by p.plid,s.codetypeid
```

Expected Result

```
plid    codetypeid  countmissingParts
84459   877490           4
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close on your what you tried query... Give this a try. Your `LEFT JOIN`, you joined the `partid` to the `plid`... Should have joined `p.partid=t.partid`

```
select p.plid,s.codetypeid,count(p.partid) as countmissingParts
from #parts p
inner join #searchdata s on s.plid=p.plid
left join #tradecode t on p.partid=t.partid
where t.partid is null
group by p.plid,s.codetypeid
```